# How to loop through all the Axios Api data and pass it to another container with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, axios, react-hooks

Would it be possible to send all the data from **Fetching Api data from TV Maze** section and send it to FetchApiData data={data}? So that I can use that value in ApiData.js component and display all the images. Currently, I'm only able to send one data or image link if I specify the values like request.data[0] or request.data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Jh1.png) etc.. I tried using map(()) inside the **Fetching Api data from TV Maze** section. When I try to pass that data to FetchApiData component, it throws the following error - cannot read medium of null.
Basically, I'm trying to create a website that would fetch Api from the TV maze website based on the value the user types on a form and then show all the TV show images which have similar titles. Any other way to display all the images fetched from the Api is okay too. I'm a beginner, so if you are unclear about the issue please let me know. Thanks in advance

App.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Nav from "./Nav";
import UseForm from "./Form"
import FetchApiData from './ApiData'
import axios from 'axios';


function App(){
    //fetching values typed by the user
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
        search: "",
        contactName:"",
        contact:""
    });
//when form is submitted run this
function onFormSubmit(event){
        setInputValue(inputValue.search)
        event.preventDefault();
    }

//fetching Api data from TV Maze    
const [data, setData] = useState([{}])
    useEffect(()=>{
        async function fetchData(){
            try{
                const request =  await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${inputValue}`) 
                let appData =  request.data[0].show.image.medium ////want to loop through all the images in this array. For eg; request.data[1].show.image.medium and so on.Not just request.data[0] 
                setData(appData)  
                return appData
                } 
            catch(err){
                console.log(err)
                }
        
    }  fetchData()
    }, [inputValue])

    return (
    <div>
        <Nav 
        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/logo.png`}
        title = "CONTACT US"
        />
        <UseForm inputValue={inputValue} setInputValue={setInputValue}
            onFormSubmit = {onFormSubmit}
        />
        {/* {send all the looped images from api here. Currently it is only sending one image} */}
            <FetchApiData data={data}/>
    </div>)
}

export default App
```

ApiData.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

// for each image fetched from App.js file i.e(<FetchApiData data={data}/>) return this div....
const FetchApiData = ({data}) =>{
    return (
            <div className="section-image">
                <img src={data} alt=""/>
            </div>
            
            ) 
}


export default FetchApiData
```

Form.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


function UseForm({inputValue, setInputValue, onFormSubmit}){

    function handleChange(e){
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        setInputValue(previousValue=>{
            if(name === "search"){
                return{
                    search: value,
                    contactName:previousValue.contactName,
                    contact:previousValue.contact   
                }
            }
        })
    }


    return ( 
        <div className="form-container">
            <div className="input-div">
                <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
                    <input className="form-input" onChange={handleChange} type="text" name="search" value={inputValue.search} placeholder="Search TV Shows"/>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn">Submit</button>    
                </form>   
            </div>
        </div>)
}



export default UseForm;
```

console.log

[image: Console.log]

Console.log 2nd half
[image: console.log-2nd half]

Now there's a new error. I pasted these URL's in postman and sent a get request. There weren't any issues.
[image]

This is one of the URLs [https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/31/78286.jpg][4]

[4]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to map response data and extract image urls.

Try something like below:-

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const request = await axios.get(
          `http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${inputValue}`
        );

        let appData = request.data.map(innerData => innerData.show?.image?.medium)
        setData(appData);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [inputValue]);
```

Comment: Getting this error now. :(
TypeError: Cannot read property 'medium' of null
    at App.js:30
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at fetchData (App.js:30)

Comment: can you share console log of `request.data`? I think in array one of property does not have `image` object.

Comment: `0: {score: 17.802393, show: {…}}
1: {score: 15.051812, show: {…}}
2: {score: 14.85622, show: {…}}
3: {score: 14.845601, show: {…}}
4: {score: 14.840906, show: {…}}
5: {score: 14.768305, show: {…}}
6: {score: 14.760103, show: {…}}
7: {score: 14.746175, show: {…}}
8: {score: 14.730987, show: {…}}
9: {score: 14.542862, show: {…}}'

Comment: `0:
score: 17.802393
show:
dvdCountry: null
externals: {tvrage: 30124, thetvdb: 220411, imdb: "tt1723816"}
genres: (2) ["Drama", "Romance"]
id: 139
image: {medium: "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/31/78286.jpg", original: "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/31/78286.jpg"}
language: "English"
name: "Girls"
network: {id: 8, name: "HBO", country: {…}}
officialSite: "http://www.hbo.com/girls"
premiered: "2012-04-15"
rating: {average: 6.6}
status: "Ended"
url: "https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/139/girls"

Comment: Can you please post whole console log in question?

Comment: Have uploaded now. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: your `data` will be array now you have to map through them and send them in `<FetchApiData data={data}/>` or else it will return error 404

Comment: Sure, will try that. Thank you:)

Comment: Wow! It worked. Thanks a lot :) Was stuck in this issue from the morning.